# Proper chord tremolo notation and execution

Tags: piano, notation, tremolo

I'm not sure if this measure from Joe Hisaishi's "Hana-Bi" is correctly notated for a chord tremolo. What is the correct notation, and how should it be played?

[image: Measure from "Hana-Bi" by Joe Hisaishi]

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to play this would be to alternate the upper two notes with the lower D. Here is one possibility.

[image: Example tremolo execution]

It could also be played faster, in the reverse order (lower note first), or with the two lower notes alternating with the top-most.

A more typical notation would show the two parts of the tremolo separately.

[image: tremolo with upper and lower elements separated]

Comment: Hi Aaron, 
Thank you very much for your answer! Sounds very reasonable and insightful. 
I have a similar question. It’s also a tremolo chord and it lasts for two measures. Which of the three notations is best? https://imgur.com/Sxaimcx  (sorry, I don't know how to insert a picture in the comment)

Comment: @June The third one is best.